# JustMock vs Moq

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mocking, moq, justmock

In order to write Unit Tests, I need to integrate a mocking framework for my WinRT based application and decide on which mocking framework would be a best fit. I ended up comparing JustMock (licensed version) and Moq. I could not find a detailed comparison between the two. However, some of the articles say that Moq is a little better as far as performance is concerned.
Any suggestion or any useful links where I can go through the detailed comparison of the two?

Answer (score 8):

Both are good testing frameworks. Both have similar syntax. Not sure about performance, but neither is horribly slow. To some extent it is a matter of personal preference. I recommend giving each one a test drive and seeing which one you prefer. Below are some links for additional reading.

[telerik-justmock-free-vs-moq](http://wbsimms.com/mocking-frameworks-telerik-justmock-free-vs-moq/)

[JustMockLite vs Moq vs RhinoMocks](https://sites.google.com/site/beaconcommsresearch/home/moq-vs-justmock-vs-rhinomocks)

[JustMock documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/help/justmock/introduction.html)

[NSubstitute-vs-Moq-vs-FakeItEasy-vs-Rhino](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201412/Blog/NSubstitute-vs-Moq-vs-FakeItEasy-vs-Rhino/)

Although it wasn't one of the frameworks you were asking about NSubstitute looks to be slightly easier to use. See [this link](http://weareadaptive.com/blog/2014/09/30/why-nsubstitute/)

MoqaLate is a newer mock framework for Windows Phone and Windows Store Apps. I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising. See [this link](https://github.com/jason-roberts/MoqaLate)

Answer (score 1):

Moq won't work for your WinRT based application (that is, WP8.1 and W8.1, it might work in 8), unless you place your testable code in a PCL that targets .NET in addition to your other targets.

There is some useful explanation in [this thread](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/214), also a [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbrit/archive/2012/06/05/say-goodbye-to-system.reflection.emit-any-dynamic-proxy-generation-in-winrt.aspx) on why WinRT broke most existing mocking frameworks.

As far as I can tell JustMock is the only mocking framework available for WinRT that isn't in alpha stage.

Comment: I think they have a POC for it: https://github.com/mbrit/moqrt Not sure how stable it is.